# "Ground into" or "Ground to"

Tags: phrase-usage, predicate-frames

I am writing a poem and I would like to convey that something is desecrated into nothing, so to speak, so I decided to go with something in the ilk of: 'twas ground (ground being past tense conjugation of grind) to sand (or) meat. my question is: would "**Ground to meat**" be correct? or would it be "**Ground into meat**"?

This question was asked previously but was "off-topic" so this is the corrected and revised variant.

Comment: Depends on context and "tone".

Comment: If I read that something was “ground [in]to meat” or “ground [in]to hamburger”, my first reaction would be “Whaaaat?  What is the author trying to say here?”  My second thought would be “Oh, is that how the burger restaurants make ‘burgers’ with no meat – they take plants and grind them into hamburger?” — but that would be a snarky thought, not a serious interpretation.  Now, if you said that ***somebody*** was ground into hamburger, my first reaction would be “Ew”, but at least it would make sense.

Comment: I just looked at [the question you asked two hours before this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/529020/26083), and I see that (1) it was closed as ‘‘off-topic’’ ***for lack of research**,* and (2) the only change you made to get this “corrected and revised variant” was to add a definition of ‘‘ground’’. See [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ground_VERB+into%2Cground_VERB+to&year_start=1750), [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ground+into%22) and [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ground+to%22) for examples of research you should have done before asking.

Comment: I apologize for that, I am new here, but I promise I will not do such a thing again. Lesson learned. Thank you all for answering regardless, I have my answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Into* is more common, but *to* would mean the same thing and might scan better.

I doubt *meat* is the best word. Meat isn't always ground. I suggest *hamburger*, just because it's ground meat. But if that doesn't fit the spirit of the poem,there are plenty of other words you could use.

Or leave it *meat*. It's a poem. Verbal precision takes back seat to effect.